# How to reopen a closed app window by clicking menuItem

Tags: swift, cocoa

I have a cocoa application with a menuItem.I am able to reopen or bring window front on clicking the app icon from dock. I want to achieve the same behaviour by clicking on the menuItem.

Here is my method that creates the Menu

```
func constructMenu() {
    let menu = NSMenu()
    menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Show Window", action:  #selector(AppDelegate.showWindow), keyEquivalent: "s"))
    statusItem.menu = menu
}
```

I have achieved window reopen on dock icon click by `applicationShouldHandleReopen` delegate method

```
func applicationShouldHandleReopen(_ sender: NSApplication, hasVisibleWindows flag: Bool) -> Bool {
    if !flag {
        for window: AnyObject in sender.windows {
            window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

I have searched in the SO for the solution. But didn't find anything that direct me to the solution.
Is there any way that I can invoke `applicationShouldHandleReopen` method? 
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Just call `makeKeyAndOrderFront` on the `mainWindow` of the `NSApplication` instance. How many windows do you have that you need a repeat loop? And don't make a distinct type `NSWindow` unspecified by annotating `AnyObject`. Remove the annotation, the compiler knows the type

Comment: I don't even know under what class you are invoking constructMenu().  Re-opening a window?  Explain which window you are referring to.

Comment: @vadian My app has only one window. Thanks for responding. I am new to Cocoa app development. Can you explain it a bit more elaborate?